# Provide access to application registered in active directory in a subscription to another Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an app `APP1` registered in AAD of subscription `S1`. I need to provide access to `APP1` in another subscription `S2` so that `APP1` can access resources in `S2`. Can this be done?
When I try to provide access to `APP1` in `S2`, I cannot find the `APP1`. Do I need to register the same `APP1` in `S2`?

Comment: Does your subscription S1 and S2 use the same Azure AD?

Comment: No they have different AAD.

Answer (score 2):

App registration is created in AAD tenant rather than subscription.

So, just make sure that the `APP1` is created in the tenant which has `S2` subscription.

Or you can create the `APP1` as multi-tenant app in AAD of subscription `S1` and then use [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) to add it into the tenant which has `S2` subscription.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of the tenant which has S2 subscription}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id of APP1}
```

Use an admin account of the tenant which has `S2` subscription to sign in to do the admin consent for that tenant.

Comment: I have APP1 created as single tenant app in S1 tenant. Now I need to create the same APP1 single tenant app in S2 tenant? 
If so how the app in S2 tenant will be linked to app in S1?
Is there an admin consent required for single tenant app ??

Comment: @ManinderChhabra No. It's impossible. You should create it as **multi-tenant app**  in S1 and use the admin consent url to add it into the tenant which has S2.

Comment: To add to @AllenWu's answer, you need to change your app from single tenant to a multi-tenant app. You can do so by going into your app registration's Authentication blade.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll create a multi tenant app and will try the admin consent.
Thanks a lot @allenwu and @gauravmantri!!

Comment: @GauravMantri Is there an API to check if admin consent has been provided for the requested tenant?